# PyQt5 ListWidget. Click an item on listWidget, but pass another item to function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a ListWidget that is populated with dates. I would like to also include a hidden value (mysql row id) that does not get displayed, however when I click a date I would like to pass the hidden row id to the function. Is something like this possible?
I'm currently using the following to call my function:

```
self.listWidget_entries.itemClicked.connect(self.get_memo_details)
```

Comment: On the face of it, this seems very easy to solve. The `itemClicked` signal emits the item that is clicked, so just store the extra values using [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData).

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `item.setData(Qt.UserRole + 1, rowid)`.

Answer (score 0):

It might look something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)      

        self.rowId = 777                                                         # <---     

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(
                lambda it, rowId=self.rowId : self.listWidgetClicked(it, rowId)) # <---

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        self.createListWidget()

    def createListWidget(self):
        for it in ["item1", "item2", "item3"]:
            self.listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem(it))
            self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)  

    @pyqtSlot() 
    def listWidgetClicked(self, item, rowId ):                                   # <---
        print('click -> {}, rowId=`{}`'.format(item.text(), rowId))


if __name__=="__main__": 
    import sys 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]